# Localizing sentences with dynamic content inserted in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, localization

I'm about to localize a web application coded in webforms (asp.net) and I am wondering about the best approach to multi part localizable content. To illustrate the problem: When you translate a sentence like: "My name is Jonhy and I'm 12 years old" if you assume the name and the age are dynamically retrieved, it may be required the change the positions of the name and the age in the translation to make it grammatically correct in the target language. I was thinking we can just use string.Format and put {0} and {1} in the resource file and let the translator deal with. I would, however, like to know if there is a better approach to achieve this? I am certain this comes up very often.

Comment: This is one of the reasons that `String.Format` works the way it does, it also allows you to have parameters that aren't included or are included multiple times with different formats... `On Wed the 7th day of january` vs `Jan 7`, etc... Both would have a date as a parameter but could be re-worded to allow localization (ok, Date's a bad example as there are good formatters for that but you get my point)

Comment: True but that means I shipping resource files to the translator that look like: My name is {0} and I'm {1} years old. Also I probably need to be careful about the use of curly brackets in the translations (even though it's not a likely thing).

Comment: You'll need to escape (double) curly braces... `It's {really} good` ... `It's {{really}} good` and yeah, that's exactly what they'll look like except you'll also need to provide some example values if the value isn't clearly implied by the sentence. I don't see how you could avoid that? There has to be a placeholder of _some_ sort. It's possible someone else can give you a better answer but I'm afraid I don't know one.

Comment: I meant on the translator's side, it's this extra information that he or she needs to be aware of. I guess it can't be avoided at least not without some significant overhead in crafting up something from scratch and if that is the solution then I'd rather stick with what we have.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the misfortune of working on the localization of lots of Microsoft software and I can tell you that this is commonplace. Localizers are used to seeing strings with placeholders and in your example ("My name is {0} and I'm {1} years old"), it's not hard to understand. You should probably add a variant for singular as the s in years will be incorrect if the value is zero or one (but I know this is only an example).

Large companies even have proprietary software to define and verify rules on individual strings, which are then used to ensure that translators don't introduce bugs such as malformed placeholders or making the string longer than is acceptable.

For placeholder strings, it's good to use the commenting feature (i.e. type into the "Comment" column in the Visual Studio resource editor) so that you can tell localizers about the placeholders and give them some example. Then they are empowered to reorder placeholders if they need to. Note however that even if you do this, localizers are fallible (and not well paid for their time) so bugs are commonplace when it comes to placeholders. A real-life example is the "{0} of {1}" string that goes to the bottom of a printed page (e.g. "1 of 3", relating to the page count). The most common French translation is the literal translation "{0} de {1}" which is incorrect in the specific context of a page count, it should be "{0} sur {1}" in this context. But most applications that do printing have this translated wrong in French. And you can't blame the translators if they have no idea how the string will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Good answer from Clafou. And it actually gets even more complicated:

*EN: You won a car. => You won a {0}*

And now you think you can put anything in there like boat, holiday, etc.

Unfortunately, in other languages the article is not always the same.

*DE: Sie haben ein Auto gewonnen.*

But

*Sie haben Ferien gewonnen* (no article) or *Sie haben eine Gurke gewonnen*. (different article). In same for Italien and other languages. So you would have to include the article into the variable.

Comment: Yes, placeholder strings are fine for things such as names or numbers, but piecing together bits of sentences is a big no-no as grammar is then likely to get in the way. With some creativity, a translator might manage to work around the grammatical problem, but it won't be pretty (example: translating "You won a {0}" with the translation of "Won: {0}" so that no article is required).